# Downloading multiple files one at a time

Tags: c#

This is the Code Below....

```
using System.Net;

   //Create Temporary Folder to Holde All the Downloads............
    namespace downloadFileCSharp10
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

      string url = "URL";
      string path = @"c:\Folder";
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      void InitiateDownload(string RemoteAddress, string LocalFile, AsyncCompletedEventHandler CompleteCallBack, object userToken)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(RemoteAddress), LocalFile, userToken);



    }

    void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            lblInfo1.Visible = true;
            lblInfo1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInfo1.Text = "Error Downloading ";

            //throw e.Error;
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            lblInfo1.Visible = true;
            lblInfo1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInfo1.Text = "Download Cancelled " + e.UserState + e.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            lblInfo1.Visible = true;
            lblInfo1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInfo1.Text = e.UserState + " Download Complete!! ";
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";


        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnGetDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                  //First Download
                 InitiateDownload(URL, path + "name you give.txt", wc_DownloadFileCompleted, "name you give.txt");
                 //Second Download
                 InitiateDownload(URL, path + "name you give2.txt", wc_DownloadFileCompleted, "name you give2.txt");

    }


     }
  }
```

When I download multiple files it downloads all at the same time and from time to time I get one or two downloads that become corrupted.  Also when I have more than 10 or 15 my application freezes a bit because its downloading all at the same.  I want to be able to download at at least one or two at a time. I have looked around in using async and await but had no luck with.  In addition I want to put a progressbar for each download file.  So basically a loop but inserted into a listview but do not know how to go about it or maybe how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2013/06/12/how-to-download-multiple-files-concurrently-using-webclient-and-the-downloadfileasync-method.aspx.

As I understand you should configure simultaneous outgoing connection limit to a higher number.

In the App.config file for the project, add the maxconnection setting:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <system.net>
      <connectionManagement>
        <addaddress = "*"maxconnection = "10" />
      </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>

</configuration>
```

Credits to upper link. But this can only explain freezes when large number of files requested. For file corruption I think another point needs to be solved.

Comment: this is done soley in c# and not asp.net.. It does not seem to be in the right direction.

Comment: App.config can be used in Winforms applications. It is not aimed for asp.net.

Comment: I keep getting The element 'connectionManagement' has invalid child element 'addadress'. List of possible elements expected: 'add, remove, clear'. and Missing attribute name.

Comment: There has to be a better way then this.  I have been read on async and await but do not know how where to implement it.

Comment: What .net version are you using?